# How to Update Account field for User by using Trigger in salesforce?

Tags: triggers, apex, account

When a new user is created, if the account name of user is `'test'`, then I want a new account created with name of user company name,
and replace it with previous account name in user details.

```
trigger UpdateAccount on User (after insert,before update) {
  Set<Id> ContactId=new Set<Id>();

  for(User us:Trigger.New){

    if(us.AccountId=='001N000000Z0W9R'){    
      ContactID.add(us.ContactId);

      for(Contact c:[select id,AccountId from Contact where id in:ContactID]){   

        Account Acc = new Account(Name=us.CompanyName);
        insert Acc;

        c.AccountId=Acc.Id;
        update c;
      }

      update us;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Stack Overflow! You should consider reading the guidelines of how to ask a good question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and possibly revise your question to fit those guidelines. With that, what have you tried so far? Do you have any APEX code to show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Problem Solved
Here is the answer***

```
 trigger UpdateAccount on User (after insert,after update)

{

Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
List<User> UserList= new List<User>();

for (User u : Trigger.new) {
    if (u.AccountId=='001N000000Z0W9R')
        contactIds.add(u.ContactId);  
        UserList.add(u);

}
 if (contactIds.size() > 0) {

        List<Contact> contacts = [select id,AccountId from Contact where Id in :contactIds];

        for (Contact c : contacts) {
            for(User u :UserList){                                                                                                                                                       
            Account acc= new Account(Name=u.CompanyName);
            acc.OwnerId = '00590000003lP6Z';
            insert acc;
            c.AccountId=acc.id;

        }
        }
      //  update UserList;
        update contacts;

    }    }
```